# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]) [REACTJS]

Tags: react

estou fazendo uma listagem de itens que possui uma chave estrangeira (om_id) . Ao recuperar essa listagem gostaria de que invés de carregar o valor om_id, viesse o valor do Nome dessa tabela OM.

Ao rendezirar o meu código estou obtendo o seguinte erro como resposta:

*Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.*

Não estou conseguindo sair dessa sinuca!

Segue meu codigo:

```html
class ListaInspecao extends Component
{

    constructor()
    {
        super();

        this.state = {
            listaInspecao: [],
            listaInfo: {},
            page: 1,
        }
    }
    

    getOmNome = async (id) =>
    {
        const response = await Api.get(`/om/${id}`);
        return response.data.nome;
 
    }

    componentWillMount()
    {
        console.log("will");
        this.LoadListaInspecao();
    }

    componentDidMount()
    {
               
    }

    LoadListaInspecao = async (page = 1) =>{
        const response = await Api.get(`/inspecao?page=${page}`);

        const{data, ...listaInfo} = response.data;
        
        this.setState({listaInspecao: data, listaInfo, page});

        console.log(data);
        
    }

    render(){
        //console.log(this.state.listaInspecao[0].nome);
        return(
            <React.Fragment>
                <h1>Lista de inspeção</h1>
                
                <div>
                    {
                        this.state.listaInspecao.map(inspecao =>(
                            <article key={inspecao.id}>
                                <strong>{inspecao.numero}</strong>
                                <p>dt_inicio: {inspecao.dt_inicio}</p>
                                <p>dt_fim: {inspecao.dt_fim}</p>
                                <p>Nome: {this.getOmNome(inspecao.om_id)}</p>
                                 {/* <p>Nome: {inspecao.om.sigla}</p>                                 */}
                            </article>
                            )
                        )
                    }
                </div>
            </React.Fragment>
        
        );
    }
}

export default ListaInspecao;
```

Desde já estou muito agradecido pela ajuda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getOmNome` é uma função `async`, isso significa que seu retorno será encapsulado dentro de uma `Promise`. Para desencapsular dados de uma promise, você pode utilizar o `await`, mas como você está fazendo isso dentro do método `render`, isso não é viável, pois o `render` não deveria ser assíncrono.

Essa abordagem não é a ideal, o certo seria fazer um `setState` quando você obter a resposta, assim como você já está fazendo no `LoadListaInspecao`, ou seja:

```js
constructor() {
  super();

  this.state = {
    listaInspecao: [],
    listaInfo: {},
    omData: [],
    page: 1,
  }
}

LoadListaInspecao = async (page = 1) => {
  const responseInspecao = await Api.get(`/inspecao?page=${page}`);

  const { data, ...listaInfo } = responseInspecao.data;

  const responseOm = await Promise.all(data.map(d => Api.get(`/om/${d.om_id}`)));

  const omData = responseOm.map(r => r.data);

  this.setState({ listaInspecao: data, listaInfo, omData, page });

}

render() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <h1>Lista de inspeção</h1>

      <div>
        {
          this.state.listaInspecao.map((inspecao, i) => (
            <article key={inspecao.id}>
              <strong>{inspecao.numero}</strong>
              <p>dt_inicio: {inspecao.dt_inicio}</p>
              <p>dt_fim: {inspecao.dt_fim}</p>
              <p>Nome: {this.state.omData[i].nome}</p>
            </article>
          ))
        }
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>

  );
}
```

Comment: Funcionou! muito obrigado meu amigo!